# socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused linux

Tags: python, linux, nagios

I just started with Nagios XI and i got this error and i cant find the right answer does anyone know what the problem is? 
I already checked the proxy and i cant find where the problem is.
The code is to get notifications messages through whats app.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 316******** --cc 31 --mcc 204 --mnc 10
yowsup-cli  v2.0.15
yowsup      v2.5.0

Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Tarek Galal
http://www.openwhatsapp.org

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://openwhatsapp.org/yowsup/donate


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 368, in <module>
    if not parser.process():
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 189, in process
    self.handleRequestCode(self.args["requestcode"], config)
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 208, in handleRequestCode
    result = codeReq.send()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yowsup/registration/coderequest.py", line 62, in send
    res = super(WACodeRequest, self).send(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 70, in send
    return self.sendGetRequest(parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 108, in sendGetRequest
    self.response = WARequest.sendRequest(host, port, path, headers, params, "GET")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 164, in sendRequest
    conn.request(reqType, path, params, headers);
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1010, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 967, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 831, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 790, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1171, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The first two things that come to my mind is that your local machine terminated the connection since it is a low port number or that the destination refused the connection because of a firewall. What port are you using locally, and can you try running that command using `sudo`? Also, is the remote host over a WAN? If so, are you sure that the host isn't behind NAT? If they are, does the NAT gateway do port forwarding?

Comment: I am using port 8080. and i tried to use the command with sudo and it gave me the same error i think my self its the firewall but i can't change that because i am on my company's network so i dont have permision for to change it.

Comment: Is the remote target a machine that is itself behind a router? Or does the target machine have a public IP address?

Comment: Try this: on the target machine, open a terminal and run `nc -l 8080` and on your local machine open a terminal a run `nc remote.ip.address.here 8080`. Then type "test" and hit enter and see if it shows up on the remote machine. `nc` is netcat, a useful tool that comes with most unix workstations. If you're on windows, you'll have to download it somewhere.

Comment: You should give me more information about what you're trying to connect to: is it a server you have control over, or a service? If it is a service, you should call them because this is just a vanilla "connection refused" error.

Comment: I'm connecting to a service the proxy is working fine. But when i try to use registration from yowsup-cli i get the 111 error

Comment: i am trying to registrate a phonenumber with the yowsup registration command and to request code on my phone